# Network request failed while fetch the data from wen URL

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am new in react native and I have a common problem while fetching the data from a web URL. As I run the following code I got the following warning and not data is retired.

**The Warning:**

> Network request failed.

**The Code:**

```
fetch('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast16?q=London&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      firstParam: 'yourValue',
      secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
    })
  })
```

Also, I tried this one and I had the same problem:

```
  fetch('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast16?q=London&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22')
       .then((response)=>response.json())
       .then((resp)=> data={resp})
       .catch( );
       console.log("data",this.resp);
  }
```

I should mention that I have this problem on Android. I searched a lot on this issue but I couldn't find a good solution. I also added the following code to the `AndroidManifest`, but the problem still exist.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Anther point that I should added is that the URL is not safe, since in Firefox it dose't show the data.

Any Idea?

Comment: working in ios ?

Comment: @Jigar: I did't check. I am just working on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to fetch from a place with broken SSL certs, you receive said error. Pages fail SSL cert verification. You need to either connect to a properly configured https page or just use the http counterparts.

Comment: I used a proxy to solve that and make it fine. Thanks for your answer. :)